# Map property with corresponding value in another property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function that gets the LCID (locale ID) from the current user. I want to map this number with the corresponding language in another property. For example, I  first extract the LCID from the user, let's say "1043" for Dutch. I have a property with "1043: Dutch" and I want to extract the name from this property with the ID.

My code:

```
export class Languages {
  public static languages = {
    1033: 'English',
    1035: 'Finnish',
    1036: 'French',
    1037: 'Hebrew',
    1038: 'Hungarian',
    1040: 'Italian',
    1041: 'Japanese',
    1042: 'Korean',
    1043: 'Dutch',
    1044: 'Norwegian',
    1045: 'Polish',
  };
}

localeId = applicationContext.pageContext.legacyPageContext.currentLanguage; //get the LCID
}

let language: any;

const pos: number = Object.keys(Languages.languages).indexOf(localeId.toString());
//WRONG BELOW
if (pos > -1) {

  let languageObject = Object.keys(Languages.languages).map(e => Languages.languages[pos]);
  language = languageObject;

  //WRONG UP
}

return language; //Should return the correct NAME of the languages via the ID
}
```

See the code where I wrote, "wrong below". It doesn't return the correct value. For example, if the localeId is 1043, then it would return "Dutch" which it doesn't.

Comment: why not `var langName = languages[localeId]`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use bracket notation:

```js
const languages = {1033:'English',1035:'Finnish',1036:'French',1037:'Hebrew',1038:'Hungarian',1040:'Italian',1041:'Japanese',1042:'Korean',1043:'Dutch',1044:'Norwegian',1045:'Polish'};
const id = 1036;
const language = languages[id];
console.log(language);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static languages = {
    1033: 'English',
   .....etc
  };
```

if the above code is in the format of localeId: Language Name.
you can access directly like Languages[localeId]